# Bootstrap select box, show blue outline on focus

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, jquery-easyui, twitter-bootstrap-2

I am using Bootstrap v2.3.2. When you focus on a Text Box or Text Area, I see a blue outline for the element. but it does not work for Select boxes. Is it a bug in bootstrap? If so, what is the alternate solution to achieve it? Also I am using Jquery Easyui framework v1.3.5 in combination with bootstrap. Is it any easyui interference that is breaking this functionality for select box?

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks,
Leela

Answer (score 0):

**You Can Use This**

```css
textarea:active,
textarea:focus,
input:active, 
input:focus,
{
   outline:0px !important;
   -webkit-appearance:none;
}
```

Comment: It did not work. Actually it is already part of Bootstrap CSS.`textarea:focus,
input:focus,
select:focus,
input[type="text"]:focus,
{
  border-color: rgba(82, 168, 236, 0.8);
  outline: 0;
  outline: thin dotted transparent  \9;
  /* IE6-9 */

  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,.075), 0 0 8px rgba(82,168,236,.6);
  -moz-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,.075), 0 0 8px rgba(82,168,236,.6);
  box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,.075), 0 0 8px rgba(82,168,236,.6);
}`

Comment: Can You make ScreenShot Of Html <Head> part ??